# Cambiar selección de ion-select según el sexo

Tags: ionic, typescript, ionic-framework, ionic3

Buenas.

Estoy teniendo un problema que quiero que si el sexo es m (se seleccione Masculino y si es f Femenino según el valor devuelto del ajax)aquí les dejo el código que tengo

Tengo esta función que se encarga de hacer la petición ajax que devuelve un json

```
obtenerConfiguracion(correo: string){
    return this.http.get(this.deezerAPI + "/api/Child?correo="+correo).map( res => res.json());
  }
```

Resultado de la función.

```
[{"Sexo":"m","Nombre":"Deivis","Color_cabello":"Negro","Color_ojos":"Pardos","Animal_favorito":"Perro","Juguete_favorito":"Pelota Futbol","Termino":"1"}]
```

Componentes configuracion.html

```
<ion-content padding>
  <form id="registro">
    <ion-list text-center>
      <ion-item class="container-item">
        <ion-label class="label-form" stacked>SEXO</ion-label>
        <ion-select name="sexo" [(ngModel)]="sexo">
          <ion-option value = "m">Masculino</ion-option>
          <ion-option value = "f">Femenino</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="container-item">
        <ion-label class="label-form" stacked>NOMBRE DEL NIÑO/A</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="nombreApellidos" name="inputNombreApellidos"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="container-item">
        <ion-label class="label-form" stacked>COLOR DE CABELLO</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="colorCabello" name="colorCabello"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="container-item">
        <ion-label class="label-form" stacked>COLOR DE OJOS</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="colorOjos" name="colorOjos"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="container-item">
        <ion-label class="label-form" stacked>ANIMAL FAVORITO</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="animalFavorito" name="animalFavorito"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item class="container-item">
        <ion-label class="label-form" stacked>JUGUETE FAVORITO</ion-label>
        <ion-input type="text" [(ngModel)]="jugueteFavorito" name="jugueteFavorito"></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>He leído y aceptado los términos y condiciones</ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox></ion-checkbox>
      </ion-item>
      <button ion-button class="btn-img-fondo" (click)="registroConfiguracion()" >GUARDAR</button>
    </ion-list>    
  </form>
</ion-content>
```

configuracion.ts

```
ionViewDidLoad() {
    let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
      content: "Cargando..."
    });
    loader.present();
    this.storage.get('correo').then((val) => {
      if(val != "" && val != undefined){
        this.usuarios.obtenerConfiguracion(val)
        .subscribe(detalles => {
          detalles.map(especifico => {
            if(especifico.Sexo != "0" && especifico.Nombre != "0" && especifico.Color_cabello != "0" && especifico.Animal_favorito != "0" && especifico.Juguete_favorito != "0"){

              //aquí lleno los input con los valores retornados del json, 
              //y quiero que si el sexo es m en el select se muestre
              // seleccionado Masculino

              this.nombreApellidos = especifico.Nombre;
              this.animalFavorito = especifico.Animal_favorito;
              this.jugueteFavorito = especifico.Juguete_favorito;
              this.colorCabello = especifico.Color_cabello;
              this.colorOjos = especifico.Color_ojos;
              this.edita = "1";
            }
            else
              this.edita = "0";
            loader.dismissAll();
          })
        });
      }
    });
  }
```

Muchas Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disculpen todo estaba en que me faltaba la siguiente linea de código

```
this.sexo = especifico.Sexo;
```